# Can MongoDB replicate to another machine?

Tags: database, mongodb, replication

This is the first time I am using MongoDB. So the question is, can MongoDB replicate to another machine (different ip)? I found some tutorial and that uses the same machine and just a different port.

Comment: yep, of course it can.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev can you give me tutorial about it ? i try but it can't :(

Comment: You can use the tutorial you have, only put the other node on another machine. It is as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

As you asked for a tutorial on setting up a MongoDB replica set, follow the official MongoDB tutorials for this: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/